# Cannot set my APK MainActivity as the Home Activity via ADB

Tags: adb, launcher, home-screen, default-applications

I am using one these AndroidTV 11.0 S905W2 boxes from Amazon and I could not make my APK the Home Activity via ADB.exe
I am using the following adb command via WiFi as connecting via a USB cable to my PC does not reveal this box.

```
adb -s 192.168.1.40:5555 shell cmd package set-home-activity "org.mumti.MUMTIG3/org.mumti.MUMTIG3.MainActivity"
```

Response is "Error: Failed to set default home."

Regarding my APK "MainActivity" aapt.exe output reveals there is a launchable-activity: name='org.mumti.MUMTIG3.MainActivity' so I don't know why adb does not succeed.

The reason adb fails setting my APK MainAcitivity may have to do with a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273739/ionic3-mainactivity-classnotfoundexception-on-android-4-4-kitkat) I read relating to the possibility that my APK is made of Java classes that are spread across more than one DEX file (Dalvik EXecutable) this is a bit of chinese to me and I am not sure if it applies.  I don't have direct control over the building of my APK as it is developed with a hybrid framework (JavaScipt/HTML/ionic/angular/cordova) and an Android/JAVA wrapper is put around it in the build process of an APK.  Perhaps there is a way to tweak the gradle build process and make adb succeed, I don't know.

I tried to increase minSDK to 22 from 21 in my config.xml but I get same error.

```
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="30" />
```

Here is the output from aapt.exe

```
 $AAPT_EXE dump badging "S:/_W/ARP/UPS.ion/SRC/UPS.ion.3/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk"
package: name='org.mumti.MUMTIG3' versionCode='29' versionName='0.0.29' platformBuildVersionName='11' platformBuildVersionCode='30' compileSdkVersion='30' compileSdkVersionCodename='11'
sdkVersion:'22'
targetSdkVersion:'30'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES'
application-label:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-af:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-am:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ar:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-as:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-az:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-be:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-bg:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-bn:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-bs:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ca:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-cs:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-da:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-de:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-el:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-en-AU:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-en-CA:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-en-GB:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-en-IN:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-en-XC:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-es:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-es-US:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-et:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-eu:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-fa:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-fi:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-fr:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-fr-CA:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-gl:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-gu:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-hi:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-hr:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-hu:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-hy:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-in:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-is:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-it:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-iw:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ja:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ka:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-kk:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-km:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-kn:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ko:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ky:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-lo:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-lt:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-lv:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-mk:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ml:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-mn:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-mr:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ms:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-my:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-nb:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ne:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-nl:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-or:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-pa:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-pl:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-pt:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-pt-BR:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-pt-PT:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ro:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ru:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-si:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sk:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sl:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sq:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sr:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sr-Latn:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sv:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-sw:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ta:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-te:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-th:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-tl:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-tr:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-uk:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-ur:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-uz:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-vi:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-zh-CN:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-zh-HK:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-zh-TW:'MUMTIG3'
application-label-zu:'MUMTIG3'
application-icon-120:'res/8X.png'
application-icon-160:'res/u3.png'
application-icon-240:'res/SD.png'
application-icon-320:'res/jy.png'
application-icon-480:'res/D2.png'
application-icon-640:'res/CG.png'
application: label='MUMTIG3' icon='res/u3.png'
launchable-activity: name='org.mumti.MUMTIG3.MainActivity'  label='MUMTIG3' icon=''
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.wifi' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission'
provides-component:'device-admin'
main
other-receivers
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'af' 'am' 'ar' 'as' 'az' 'be' 'bg' 'bn' 'bs' 'ca' 'cs' 'da' 'de' 'el' 'en-AU' 'en-CA' 'en-GB' 'en-IN' 'en-XC' 'es' 'es-US' 'et' 'eu' 'fa' 'fi' 'fr' 'fr-CA' 'gl' 'gu' 'hi' 'hr' 'hu' 'hy' 'in' 'is' 'it' 'iw' 'ja' 'ka' 'kk' 'km' 'kn' 'ko' 'ky' 'lo' 'lt' 'lv' 'mk' 'ml' 'mn' 'mr' 'ms' 'my' 'nb' 'ne' 'nl' 'or' 'pa' 'pl' 'pt' 'pt-BR' 'pt-PT' 'ro' 'ru' 'si' 'sk' 'sl' 'sq' 'sr' 'sr-Latn' 'sv' 'sw' 'ta' 'te' 'th' 'tl' 'tr' 'uk' 'ur' 'uz' 'vi' 'zh-CN' 'zh-HK' 'zh-TW' 'zu'
densities: '120' '160' '240' '320' '480' '640'
native-code: 'arm64-v8a' 'armeabi-v7a' 'x86' 'x86_64'
```

Addendum1: I learned about logcat and posting the tail here with
"$ADBW logcat -d -v time > logcat.txt"

I put a pair of ===BEGIN ===END around the lines that I think pertain to failure of set-home-activity.

```
04-05 12:29:08.014 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:09.116 I/chromium(27522): [INFO:CONSOLE(236)] "12:29    UserActivityTracker.Start. >>D---  this.MinutesOfInnactivity 7", source: https://localhost/build/main.js (236)
04-05 12:29:09.688 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:11.025 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:11.688 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:13.688 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:14.032 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:15.688 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:17.040 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:17.689 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:19.689 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:20.050 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:21.053 I/Finsky  ( 5139): [8519] fyo.run(10): Stats for Executor: BlockingExecutor iar@5bd16ca[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 25]
04-05 12:29:21.054 I/Finsky  ( 5139): [8519] fyo.run(10): Stats for Executor: LightweightExecutor iar@8b0703b[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 84]
04-05 12:29:21.689 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:21.823 I/Finsky  ( 5139): [8519] fyo.run(10): Stats for Executor: bgExecutor iar@df3f358[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 284]
04-05 12:29:23.059 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:23.690 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:24.386 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(  583): Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10055; state: DISABLED
04-05 12:29:24.386 D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(  583): Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10055; state: DISABLED
04-05 12:29:24.404 D/Zygote  (  297): Forked child process 6940
04-05 12:29:24.408 I/ActivityManager(  583): Start proc 6940:com.android.permissioncontroller/u0a55 for service {com.android.permissioncontroller/com.android.permissioncontroller.role.service.RoleControllerServiceImpl}
04-05 12:29:24.409 I/Zygote  ( 6940): seccomp disabled by setenforce 0
04-05 12:29:24.428 I/adbd    (28115): jdwp connection from 6940
04-05 12:29:24.470 D/ApplicationLoaders( 6940): Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.test.base.jar
04-05 12:29:24.558 D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 6940): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
04-05 12:29:24.559 D/NetworkSecurityConfig( 6940): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
===BEGIN
04-05 12:29:24.589 I/CarUiInstaller( 6940): CarUiInstaller started for com.android.permissioncontroller
04-05 12:29:24.618 W/Role    ( 6940): Cannot get ApplicationInfo for default holder: com.android.messaging
04-05 12:29:24.633 W/Role    ( 6940): org.mumti.MUMTIG3 not qualified for android.app.role.HOME due to missing RequiredComponent{mIntentFilterData=IntentFilterData{mAction='android.intent.action.MAIN', mCategories='[android.intent.category.HOME]', mDataScheme='null', mDataType='null'}, mPermission='null'}
04-05 12:29:24.633 E/RoleControllerServiceImpl( 6940): Package does not qualify for the role, package: org.mumti.MUMTIG3, role: android.app.role.HOME
04-05 12:29:25.690 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
===END
04-05 12:29:26.070 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
04-05 12:29:27.690 E/ocessService0:(27600): failed to create Unix domain socket: Operation not permitted
04-05 12:29:29.082 E/WifiVendorHal(  583): getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_UNKNOWN, .description = unknown error}
```

Comment: Have you checked `adb logcat` if it displays more details why the command fails?

Comment: I'd assume Android TV expects [Leanback support](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start), though I don't have any experience with it either.

Comment: @Robert I looked up "logcat" command and updated the post thank you.

Comment: Your app is not built to use Roles. To be set as home activity (technically a home launcher) by that cmd package command this app has to have HOME role provisions coded in. It is failing that test (see error at `04-05 12:29:24.633` and later). See HOME role in [Android Roles](https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/android-roles#HOME) if you are a developer keen on fixing this problem (don't know how). Failure occurs [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/fullsdk/sources/android-29/+/refs/heads/androidx-core-core-role-release/android/app/role/RoleManager.java#328)

Comment: @Firelord I browsed the folder platforms\android\app\src\main and found AndroidManifest.xml (probably auto generated by this ionic hybrid framework to target Android) I could post as I don't know how to correctly add to it this ROLE and leanback support requirements.  Alternatively could you point me to a "skeleton sample" Kotlin project that I could tackle to be the main launcher and in turn launches my APK?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Just a note that app development is off-topic since Android Enthusiasts focuses on end-users and power users (who are not necessarily developers) solving their issues. Thus, while the community might explain the technicality of Android OS to your queries, coding solutions are out of the scope of this community. For programming questions, you might want to try [so].

Comment: Like Andrew said you'd have to ask about this at [so]. I don't know how to fix this problem either.